# How to structure a multi-level model for a five-a-side football problem

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian

I'm working in an unfamiliar Bayesian context here, so apologies if my terminology isn't entirely correct!

Imagine I'm trying to predict the performance of players on a of a five-a-side football team.  The team has seven players, and in any given game only 5 play.  My outcome variable is the goal difference in the match, and the input data is the players, plus other controls.

I can use dummy variables to create a binary variable for each player, and use them as a predictor in the model - but what I really want to do is take advantage of partial pooling to more efficiently predict the effect of player performance.

I'd know how to do this if there was only *one player* per match - then I'm just creating a multilevel model with 'player' as a categorical variable - but I don't know how (or if) I can do this when there are multiple players per game.

Does anyone have any thoughts about this or references I can read more at?

Comment: Are you trying to estimate how good the players are based on the results of the games where they did vs did not contribute?

Comment: Hi George - yep, exactly.  As I said in the post, I know I can do this in a simple model with binary variables but it feels like a multilevel approach would be more efficient and it irks me that I can't find anything on how to do it!